# Nan en Pascal al trabajar con valores de una matriz

Tags: matrices, pascal, freepascal

Estoy desarrollando un programa en Pascal que coge un matriz y le va asignando a cada casilla la media de las 4 casiilas adyacentes durante n repeticiones.

```
for contador:= 1 to itera do
begin
    for i := 0 to width-1 do 
    begin


        for z := 0 to height-1 do
        begin
        if(mapnew[i][z].modifi) then

            mapnew[i][z].pot := ( map[i+1][z].pot+map[i][z+1].pot+map[i-1][z].pot+map[i][z-1].pot)/4;

        end;
    end;
    map:= mapnew;
end;
```

El problema es que cuando lo ejecuto e imprimo la matriz con la que trabajo me salen en los valores modificados Nan. Se que es not a number, pero me gustaria que mostrara el resultado pero no se como modificarlo.

Answer (score 0):

¿Pudiste resolver el problema?. Has tenido en cuenta que sucede en los bordes de la matriz?.

Si la linea:

```
if(mapnew[i][z].modifi) then
```

Se creó con el fin de leer el interior de la matriz sin tomar los bordes para no leer fuera cuando `i` o `z` sean igual a `0` o sean del valor máximo. Esto va a traer como consecuencia que el borde no se modificase. En la primera pasada va a ser la resultante el valor con el que se inicialice `mapnew[borde][borde].pot` y las sucesivas iteraciones lo va a tomar como valor de referencia.

Esto se debe a la linea:

```
map:= mapnew;
```

Si aún tenes el desafío pendiente y puedes compartir un poco mas del código, deberíamos poder resolverlo. También sería bueno que dieras un ejemplo del resultado esperado, como para tener en cuenta de donde tomamos los valores cuando estamos en el punto `0,0` o `Max`, `Max` de la matriz.